# Is there a way to use the normal of a face to model something else?

Tags: modeling, normals

I was wondering if there's a way to extract the normal of a specifici face to use it later in something else

In my case what i'm trying to do is a pipe that, in its start point, goes perpendicular to a specific face of my model. So it would be useful to use the normal of the model to start a spline.

heres a pic:
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Would this pipe be another mesh object, or part of the same mesh? Because there's object snapping with alignment supports (aligns Z to normal).

Comment: I need it to be a separate object at the end but i'll start for this, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also select the face, then "view->align view to selected->front" (shift Numpad <kbd>1</kbd>) and then change the 3d manipulator to "view" (instead of "global" or "local"). Then you can extrude a vertex along the normal by pressing "<kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>" or "<kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>" or use the manipulator to move along the aligned view axis.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [snapping tools](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Snap_to_Mesh#Snapping_Modes) to snap an object to the face of another object, the optional align rotation can also be beneficial.

For even more control you can use the face to define your own [custom transformations](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Transform_Orientations#Custom_Orientations) so you can move and rotate in alignment with the face.